# Como colocar um título na legenda do angular-chart

Tags: javascript, chartjs, angular-chart

No meu gráfico de linhas queria que quando passar o mouse na linha do gráfico ao aparecer a legenda, e que ela tivesse um título. Isso so é possível preenchendo o array de labels, porem aparece em baixo do gráfico, no eixo "X" os nomes, e eu não quero, quero apenas os títulos nas legendas.

Segue o código:

```
angular.module("app", ["chart.js"]).controller("LineCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.labels = ["Titulo 1", "Titulo 2", "Titulo 3", "Titulo 4", "Titulo      5", "Titulo 6", "Titulo 7"];
    $scope.series = ['Legenda 1', 'Legenda 2'];
    $scope.data = [
        [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40],
        [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]
    ];
    $scope.onClick = function(points, evt) {
        console.log(points, evt);
    };
});
```

Dessa forma, ele gera um titulo sobre as legendas ao passar o mouse, porem aparece os nomes abaixo do gráfico, eu queria que não aparecesse os nomes abaixo do gráfico, somente no título mesmo ao passar o mouse, como ficaria?
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Referência: http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/

**jsfiddle**:http://jsfiddle.net/Lfmhcab3/4/

Comment: Alguem??? ......

Comment: Isso não é possível e o criador do Chart.js [recomenda que você crie uma outra extensão para o gráfico de linhas](https://github.com/nnnick/Chart.js/issues/12#issuecomment-47473304) e realize o tratamento. Nessa mesma issue existem soluções alternativas que podem ser úteis para você.

Comment: Talvez esse link possa te ajudar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32841302/hide-labels-on-x-axis-chartjs

Comment: Veja que a legenda não aparece quando você passa o mouse sobre a linha e sim sobre o ponto.

Answer (score 3):

A parte de mudar o conteúdo da tootlip podes fazer assim, modificando o `multiTooltipTemplate`:

```
// Chart.js Options
$scope.options = {
  multiTooltipTemplate: '<%= datasetLabel + ": " + value %>',
```

Para remover a legenda do eixo X é mais complicado. Tem havido discussões longas sobre isso ([1](https://github.com/nnnick/Chart.js/issues/12), [2](https://github.com/nnnick/Chart.js/pull/897), [3](https://github.com/nnnick/Chart.js/pull/521)) mas parece que ainda não há nada implementado nesse sentido. Dá para esconder o eixo Y com `scaleShowLabels: false`, mas não o eixo X...

Uma opção seria esconder ambos os labels com `showScale: false,` ([exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/8z5gp995/)).

Porém é possivel modificar os métodos da biblioteca e baseado na sugestão que o [@potatopeelings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36558692/2256325) te deu no SOen podes fazer assim:

```
var originalLineInitialize = Chart.types.Line.prototype.initialize;
Chart.types.Line.prototype.initialize = function(data) {
    var originalLabels = data.labels.slice();
    data.labels = new Array(data.labels.length);
    originalLineInitialize.apply(this, arguments);

    this.scale.xLabels = originalLabels;
    this.datasets.forEach(function(dataset) {
        dataset.points.forEach(function(point, i) {
            point.label = originalLabels[i];
        });
    });

    var originalScaleDraw = this.scale.draw;
    this.scale.draw = function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.xLabels.length; i++) {
            this.xLabels[i] = '';
        }
        originalScaleDraw.apply(this, arguments);
    }
}
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8z5gp995/1/

Answer (score 2):

Use `scaleFontSize: false` e `scaleLabel: "<%= ' ' + value%>"` no `$scope.options`.

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rapa09/fph4jecj/5/

Comment: fui notar agora, ele tira o texto dos lados também, vou arrumar.

Comment: Arrumado e editado!

Comment: Fui ver em outro computador meu e ficou cortando, caso isso ocorra com você use: scaleLabel: "<%= '   ' + value%>" <-Isso serve para dar um espaço antes das labels laterais aonde tem '' coloque espaços(no máximo 2 espaços são aceitos!)

Fonte: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26498171/how-do-i-prevent-the-scale-labels-from-being-cut-off-in-chartjs

Answer (score 1):

Adicione `legend="false"` no canvas que está sendo gerado o chart, dentro do arquivo html.

Comment: isso desabilita a legenda, eu nao quero desabilitar a legenda, quero desabilitar os labels em baixo, mas deixar o titulo ao passar o mouse, coloquei uma imagem, na imagem mostra que quero aquele titulo da legenda, e não quero q o mesmo apareça em baixo.

Comment: coloquei o jsfidle, veja que ao passar o mouse na linha aparece os dias da semana no titulo, aquilo eu quero, so nao quero que apareça em baixo.